# Ionic $http error 404 using cordova whitelist

Tags: android, cordova, xmlhttprequest, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

My application, a simple ionic app with a $hhtp.get request, does not work after PhoneGap Build on my Android Phone. When I debug it gives me a 404 error.
When I run it on my laptop using the ionic serve -p $PORT command it gives me a CORS error.
It does work in Chrome on my laptop if I activate the CORS plug-in.
I am coding on c9 (cloud 9) and building on Adobe PhoneGap.

**My request**

```
.controller('teamCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window) {
  $http.get("http://google.com")
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.categories = getArray(response);
      var b =1;
    })
    .error(function(response) {
      $window.alert("d'oh!"); 
    });
})
```

**My CSP in index.html :**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

**config.xml :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.openorganix919048" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>OpenOrganix</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Cordova whitelist plugins are installed.

I've tried using interceptors to add the following header:

```
<Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *>
```

I've read everywhere that Cordova Whitelist should take care of this though... pls help me!

Comment: first check whether you installed cordova-plugin-whitelist in your project by typing the cmd as ionic plugin ls

Comment: @Marc, in your config.xml, what do you have for the `whitelist` plugin reference ?

Comment: Hi Anil, here is the plugin list...it is present: `com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"`

Comment: @andre3wap, thx, but I'm not sure what you mean by reference. Can you please provide an example? - I added the whole config.xml on top.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is worked for me please for only mobile devices not on web browser's. Please check it 
 update your html code if you are using the mobile device's as

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

create a button to test it as

```
<button class="button button-bar button-balanced" ng-click="whitelist()">Test it</button>
```

and the last step in your controller the code will be

```
$scope.whitelist = function(){

    console.log('method called');

    $http.get("https://www.google.co.in/").then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $scope.categories = data.status;
      console.log($scope.categories);
     }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
      $window.alert("d' oh!");
     });

  }
```

In your config.xml file the code must be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.rangeslider745642" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>rangeslider</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Hi Anil... What are you building the application with?

Comment: I am building the application with Ionic framework @Marc-AndréLanglais

Comment: If you want, I will upload a demo project in github @Marc-AndréLanglais

Comment: Like I mentioned in the post I am building with PhoneGap as I cannot install android SDK on cloud 9 due to the space restriction on my account.

Comment: The application works when compiled with ionic on my local machine... so I think we can log this one in the Adobe PhoneGap Build problems. Thx much Anil.

Comment: You are building the application on cloud 9 .. Great @Marc-AndréLanglais

Comment: please, Don't forget to inform if you get any update from Adobe PhoneGap Build

Answer (score 0):

Solved!! The problem is that the build via ionic cli will link everything together without a problem. However, the build.phonegap.com build by adobe does not. You have to specify the plug-in in the config file regardless if the plugin is already present in the project. So to the config.xml file add: `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />`and of course don't forget to add `xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"`

Comment: To clarify what @Marc-Andre has said. With *Phonegap Build* you add plugins by adding the to the `config.xml`. This means you do NOT have to add each plugin more than one, you add it once in the `config.xml` and maintain it in the config.xml. Example online show this, although typically the documentation is not read.